# Is FlipFluids still relevant in version 2.93+ of Blender?

Tags: physics

Im considering getting the FlipFluids add-on as mantaflow seems to be just too inconsistent for me. Any thoughts on this? With version 3.0 coming soon is it worth it to get the add-on now?

Comment: Depends what you mean with "relevant". If you want a quicker and much faster result than mantaflow - i can recommend using FlipFluids. I do all my fluid simulation with it and i am very satisfied with the result. But i am sure some guys have different opinions on this here.